# How to find next execution time from ScheduleExpression (Need help)

Tags: timer, ejb, java-ee-6, cronexpression, timer-jobs

I am writing a JEE JAX-RS application and I have ScheduleExpressions as a cron expression (* 1 * * *) configured in the database.
In my post construct I am creating timer service to run job periodically.

Now I want to expose a rest URI to list all timer scheduled jobs which are scheduled to run for today.

Currently I am using the following way to find the next schedule time.
Code:
 ***EJBCronTrigger trigger = new EJBCronTrigger(scheduleExpression);
 Date fireTimeAfter = trigger.getFireTimeAfter(new Date());***

Can any one suggest any other better or recommended way to find the next schedule time from a ScheduleExpression. Is there any kind of library exists.

Comment: If you're calling `TimerService.createTimer`, can you use `Timer.getNextTimeout`?

Comment: Yes, I can, But I want to expose this as a rest resource where one can find the schedule jobs running for a given date. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: I found another way using Spring,Check CronSequenceGenerator in spring framework. It provides a method next(Date). To construct CronSequenceGenerator object one must pass the Crontab expression.

Answer (score 0):

```
public String checkTimerStatus() {
            Timer timer = null;
            Collection<Timer> timers = service.getTimers();
            Iterator<Timer> iterator = timers.iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                timer = iterator.next();
                return ("Timer will expire after " +
                        timer.getTimeRemaining() + " milliseconds.");
            }
            return ("No timer found");
        }
```